# How to use a local variable in Caml Query? C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, caml-query

I have a caml query and I have a list item in SharePoint list named `testb` and it is of DateTime type. But I was wondering if I could use a local variable like one I declared `testBdate`. Can I use `testBdate` or how to use a variable like this in `<FieldRef Name =''` ?

```
DateTime testBdate = DateTime.Now;

queryMuaj.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name ='testb' Ascending = 'TRUE'/>" +
                      "</OrderBy>" +
                      "<Where>" +
                      "<And>" +
                      "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Kompania' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selvalcomp + "</Value></Eq>"+
                      "<And>" +
                            "<Geq>" +
                             "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Geq>" +
                            "<Leq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Leq> " +
                          "</And>" +
                          "</And>" +
                       "</Where>";
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly at a higher level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Name** Attribute is Optional Text that provides the **internal name of the field** that is referenced.

So try to create a new variable that will hold the internal name of your field and set it via `String.Format`

```
string FileReferenceInternalFieldName = "internal field name";


queryMuaj.Query =  String.Format("@<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name ='{0}' Ascending = 'TRUE'/>" +
                      "</OrderBy>" +
                      "<Where>" +
                      "<And>" +
                      "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Kompania' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selvalcomp + "</Value></Eq>"+
                      "<And>" +
                            "<Geq>" +
                             "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Geq>" +
                            "<Leq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Leq> " +
                          "</And>" +
                          "</And>" +
                       "</Where>", FileReferenceInternalFieldName);
```

See also [Create dynamic caml query in sharepoint](http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/03/08/create-dynamic-caml-query-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime testBdate = DateTime.Now;
string testBdateISO = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(testBdate);
```

And in the CAML:

```
<FieldRef Name='yourfieldname'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + testBdateISO + "</Value>
```